# How to create a 2D array in Python where each column has a different and random number of elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, montecarlo

I'm writing a Monte Carlo simulation of photons arriving at a detector. The total number of detected photons `N_detected` follows a Poisson distribution (which I'm generating using `scipy.stats.poisson`) and the time of detection of every single photon follows a given probability distribution function (PDF). In order to generate the time of detection of the `N_detected` photons I generate `N_detected` random numbers between 0 and 1 with the `numpy.random.random()` function and use the [Inverse Transform Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

I have to run the simulation several times. So, in order to avoid iterating a lot of times, I'd like to do every simulation at once using numpy arrays. As a final result, I'd like to obtain a 2D array of `N_sim` columns where every column corresponds to a different simulation and contains the generated times of detection. The problem is that each simulation produces a different number of photons (since it's random) and I don't find the way to create the 2D arrray with columns of different lengths.

One idea I had is creating all the columns with the same length (the largest `N_deteceted`) and fill the not needed elements with `NaN` and the rest with the random numbers I need, but I don't know I could do that.

This is the best I've been able to do so far:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from scipy.stats import poisson

beta = 0.0048    # Parameter of the PDF

""" Inverse of the time CDF (needed for the Inverse transform method) """

def inverse_time_cdf(x):
    return -np.log( (np.exp(-1000*beta)-1)*x + 1 )/beta


""" Simulation of N_sim experiments through the inverse transfrom method """

T = 1000    # Duration of the experiment [s]
rate = 3.945    # [events/s]
lam = rate*T    # Poisson distribution parameter

def photon_arrival_simulation(N_sim):
    N_detection = poisson.rvs(lam, size = N_sim)    # Number of detections in each experiment
    t = np.array([inverse_time_cdf(np.random.random(N)) for N in N_detection])

    return N_detection, t
```

If possible, I wanted to avoid the loop used in the list comprehension of the `photon_arrival_simulation()` function and also obtain a 2D array instead of an array of arrays (since I can't do array operation such as taking a `log` on an array of arrays).

I don't know if I should be posting this question here or in [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), but thanks in advance to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to make a random array with variable lengths along the rows to fill with NaN values without looping somewhere. But here is how you can resolve the 2d array issue you had, you had the right idea to use NaN. I would definitely use NaN over masked arrays since masked arrays are more for convenience than for performance. Also you should place the docstrings in their appropriate place beneath the function declarations.

```
def photon_arrival_simulation(N_sim):
    """Simulation of N_sim experiments through the inverse transform method"""

    N_detection = poisson.rvs(lam, size=N_sim)

    rand = np.random.random((len(N_detection), N_detection.max()))

    for i, N in enumerate(N_detection):
        rand[i, N:] = np.nan

    t = inverse_time_cdf(rand)

    return N_detection, t
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was thinking about (although I was trying to avoid loops, the one you used seems unavoidable and pretty straight forward). 
The ```numpy.ma``` module is imported for further code (I need to select and count those times between 200 and 201 seconds), but thanks for the comment about performance.

Also, I'll change the docstrings. I'm very keen on keeping my code as clear as possible but they don't pay much attention to these kind of things at my programming lessons at the university.